# Difference between ZRAM and ZSWAP

Tags: linux-kernel

Does anyone know what is the difference between feature ZRAM and ZSWAP in linux kernel? Seems they are very similar-- store compressed pages in ram.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**ZRAM** is a module of the Linux kernel, previously called "compcache". ZRAM increases performance by avoiding paging on disk and instead uses a compressed block device in RAM in which paging takes place until it is necessary to use the swap space on the hard disk drive. Since using RAM is faster than using disks, zram allows Linux to make more use of RAM when swapping/paging is required, especially on older computers with less RAM installed.

**ZSWAP** is a lightweight compressed cache for swap pages. It takes pages that are
in the process of being swapped out and attempts to compress them into a
dynamically allocated RAM-based memory pool.  zswap basically trades CPU cycles
for potentially reduced swap I/O.  This trade-off can also result in a
significant performance improvement if reads from the compressed cache are
faster than reads from a swap device.

Comment: Compcache is actually a different swap-only (not generic block device) implementation. They are not the same thing, and can co-exist on the same system (although there's little point in that).

Answer (score 60):

### zram

- **Status**: Available in mainline kernel as of version 3.14 (March 2014)
- **Implementation**: compressed block device, memory is dynamically
  allocated as data is stored
- **Usage**: Configure zram block device as a swap device to eliminate need
  for physical swap defice or swap file
- **Benefits**:

  1. Eliminates need for physical swap device. This beame popular when
     netbooks first showed up. Zram (then compcache) allowed users to
     avoid swap shortening the lifespan of SSDs in these memory
     constrained systems.
  2. A zram block device can be used for other applications other than
     swap, anything you might use a block device for conceivably.
- **Drawbacks**:

  1. Once a page is stored in zram it will remain there until paged in or
     invalidated. The first pages to be paged out will be the oldest
     pages (LRU list), these are 'cold' pages that are infrequently
     access. As the system continues to swap it will move on to pages
     that are warmer (more frequently accessed), these may not be able to
     be stored because of the swap slots consumed by the cold pages. What
     zram can not do (compcache had the option to configure a block
     backing device) is to evict pages out to physical disk. Ideally you
     want to age data out of the in-kernel compressed swap space out to
     disk so that you can use kernel memory for caching warm swap pages
     or free it for more productive use.

### zswap

- **Status**: Available in mainline kernel as of version 3.11 (September 2013)
- **Implementation**: compressed in-kernel cache for swap pages. In-kernel
  cache is compressed, the compression algorithm is pluggable using the
  CryptoAPI and the storage for pages is dynamically allocated. Older
  pages can be evicted to disk making this a sort of write-behind
  cache.
- **Usage**: Cache swap pages destined for regular swap devices (or swap
  files).
- **Benefits**:

  1. Integration with swap code (using Frontswap API) allows zswap to
     choose to store only pages that compress well and handle memory
     allocation failures, in those cases pages are sent to the backing
     swap device.
  2. Oldest pages in the cache are pushed out to backing swap device to
     make room for newer pages, this solves the LRU inversion problem
     that a lack of page eviction would present.
- **Drawbacks**:

  1. Needs a physical swap device (or swapfile).